# What is the relationship between charge and mass of electrons and protons?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, electrons, charge, protons

Proton and electron have equal and opposite charge but they have a different mass how is this possible

Comment: Why would you think the charge something has should correlate with its mass in a certain way?

Comment: They have different mass but both are having same charge where does that extra charge comes from

Comment: You mean extra mass? Again, why do you think charge should depend on mass?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to compare positron and electron. These have the same mass. They are more or less the same thing, except for charge. On the other hand, a proton is a completely different kind of object.

Comment: @user47014 thank you sir.. now I got it

Answer (score 2):

In the past 200 years physicists have manage to model mathematically the data from innumerable experiments, and this is the present model.

All the data show that the particles called electrons have a charge opposite to the charge of the protons. They also show the enormous mass difference.  The models created on this observation are continually validated by experiments, in particle physics, in  atomic physics, in nuclear physics.

So the answer is, that is the way nature is.

Answer (score 0):

This is just due to the nature of each particle. Each particle has mass and charge unrelated to each other.

An analogy would be types of foods. Celery might contain more fiber per calorie gained, as opposed to cookies, which have very low amounts of fiber per calorie gained. This is simply because fiber and calories have no clear relation.